# Work recognition - is this a lesson something i have to learn?

Tags: management, work-environment

My daily job involves working on a legacy project and full of hectic work. We can say our code repository is an example of spaghetti code with all violations of a maintainable code and can be taken as a best example of how a code base is not supposed to be. Our manager is also an arrogant person, who always abuses and ask completely irrational things. No one in entire whole team knows what are the requirements and each issue and new feature takes weeks and months to work, and we can't guarantee the outcome because we have no unit tests and we are not confident on not breaking anything by fixing / adding on given task. From our management side, they are very much know that, the project is not in a good position and the team is suffering a lot. Management suggests like, *ignore all the issues and do your best* kind of.

Being in this situation, in some other project, they have asked me for help regarding some deployment strategy. I have worked very hard and spent lot of time on that project also and balanced both the project for nearly two weeks working long hours. Any issue came in another project also i have taken initiative and resolved with priority, because, i have to do it otherwise it won't be resolved. The team also know, how valuable i am in that project.

But, in a meeting happened 1 day back, the management even not mentioned my name in the project status and success meet and appreciated all other team members. Clearly everyone from management know how i have worked for that project and taken all the heated discussion from client of that project.

I don't know, whether it is correct or not, expecting appreciation and recognition for the work we have done but coming to work my name comes into picture and for at least recognition they didn't remember who has worked and uplifted the project. I am trying to ignore and just move on, but it comes in my mind recurring.

Working in this workplace as a whole, what i have to learn...?

Comment: "`Working in this workplace as a whole, what i have to learn`" - you have to learn how to update your CV

Answer (score 2):

Good things: This sounds like a golden opportunity to show leadership, strength of character, initiative, and the ability to transcend the status quo. You're also taking some action by posting here to improve that situation.

You *can* learn how to deal with absolute garbage situations. A lot of management isn't there because of their ability to do the day to day work, but to handle the *exceptions* to that work.

Bad things: You sounds really frustrated and discouraged, which could affect your ability to be the change necessary to improve the situation and be the kind of person your coworkers look to. You might need to use this project to bail out.

---

What you can do:

- Implement unit and integration testing along the public interfaces in your code
- Quarantine the spaghetti to it's public interfaces and write generic interfaces that can be attached to when you eventually get to replace that hot garbage
- Don't *ignore* the issues, but stop griping about that. Make sure you're completing the tickets that are priorities, then get back to improving the situation
- Look for new work while you do this (if so inclined). I bet the PRs and documentation has your name all over it. Use this to your advantage and learn when to pull out of a sinking ship (if you want to).
- Recognize the contribution of the team to the work. It's never a solo effort. If your manager (whom you don't respect) doesn't give you the recognition you feel you deserve, does it matter so much? Your team knows. If they respect you, you can take them with you when you leave. If they don't respect the boss, but do respect you, you become the defacto supervisor for the team.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your situation but it sounds like the meeting was about the other project--not your daily, main project.

There are a couple of reasons why you weren't acknowledged.

1. You're working unofficially on it. If that group's manager admits
   he's using 'outside' resources, he could get in trouble. If your
   manager doesn't know you're doing it, you could get into trouble.
2. Because you're not on that manager's list-of-people, he forgot you.

If you have a good relationship with that manager, mention it to him: "Boss2, I notice that you didn't include me on the team list in last week's meeting. Is there a reason why not?"

If you don't want to be that direct and you have a friend on that team, see if they'll do it. "Boss, I just realized that *developer* was left off in last week's meeting. He's been really helpful."